# File system change

Tags: files, system, ext4, fat32

Is there any way to convert ext4 file system to fat32 file system by linux terminal. I now have Ubuntu focal fossa 20.04 is installed in my pc. Plz tell both methods if or not data loss.

Comment: Filesystem conversions *always* involve data loss, since you need to reset the filesystem table that contains the directory structure and the list of files. Are you doing this for a harddrive/SSD/USB flashdisk?

Comment: There is no *convert*. You must *reformat* to the new filesystem. All data will be destroyed when you do so (it is *reformatting!*)

Comment: @wyphan Yes I am doing it for my hard drive.

Comment: You can't use fat32 as a file system for Linux.